# Recording me write my notes and my speech at my desk

Tags: video-recording, camcorder, microphone

I am looking for a fairly cheap set-up (budget: ~C$200) to do the following:

- videotape the set of notes that I am writing;
- record my speech as I explain what I am writing.

An example of what I am trying to achieve is [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=68wWFt3IbvY&ab_channel=TaylorDupuy%27sMathVlog). Any kind of pointer would help as I have no idea about how I should go about this.

Answer (score 3):

First, you need a smartphone, such as iPhone or Android.  Then you need something to hold it over your notes, such as [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00UTD4XV0).  Then you need diffuse lighting at or above the level of your smartphone, one illuminating the left side of your notes, the other the right side of your notes.  If your lighting is very diffuse, then shadows should not be a problem as you write from one side of the page to another.  These [work lights](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0023QRKFW) might do the trick.  You'll have to figure out how you want to suspend them, however.

Finally, you need video editing software that lets you trim your video so your beginnings and endings are crisp and where you want them to be.  You can download a free version of DaVinci Resolve that works on Mac and Windows platforms and can output FullHD (but not UHD) video.  You can use the microphone built into your phone.